# How to move a tab to another tab container?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to impl. a 'Split Horizontal' feature for dijit.TabContainer.

I tried :

otherTabContainer.addChild(tabToMove) and also variations of removeChild and addChild but I always endup with a very weird behavior. It seems the source tab-container contain retains a reference to the tab of interest. However, I also tried to move the tab's domNode to a temp. location in order to save it from removeChild's destructive nature but still no success.

Any ideas ?

thank you!

Comment: `removeChild` doesn't destroy the widget, so you should be able to call `removeChild` on the first `TabContainer` then `addChild` on the other one.  Can you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the desired content pane widget from first tab and add it to second tab.

```
var parent1 = dijit.byId("tabcontainerId1");
var parent2 = dijit.byId("tabcontainerId2");
var tab = dijit.byId("contentPaneId");
parent1.removeChild(tab);
parent2.addChild(tab);
```

Comment: hi, that's what I thought in the first place, but no, doesn't work in my case, I will try to file a reproducible issue. thanks!

Comment: confirmed: it was my fault that it didn't work out. thanks again!